# How do I make multiline headers that don't run into the rest of the document?

Tags: spacing, header-footer

I have been trying to figure out how you make headers that are more than 3 lines tall without running into the main body of the document, but have so far been unsuccessful. I know that I could simply put space after the header inside the document, but that's be a pain to do on every page.

This is what I have:
`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fancyheadings}

\pagestyle{fancyplain}

\lhead{\begin{small}Prof. _________\\Spring 2013\end{small}\\ so \\ keep \\ it}
\chead{\begin{small}\textbf{MEE: ________}\\Homework II\footnote{This document was made using \LaTeX\ and the amsmath package.}\end{small}\\ if \\ typing \\run}
\rhead{\begin{small}____________\\Due ______________\end{small}\\ I \\ will\\ over?}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} %removes line under header
\renewcommand{\headheight}{\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item This is a homework problem. The header is overlapping this text in this current setup \\
\\
\item This is another problem. The header probably also overlaps this one. \\
\\
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

`

Edited for completeness

Comment: Wellcome to TeX SX! Please provide a Minimal Working Example (MWE). It is easier for people to run your document and help you.

Answer (score 2):

I would vote against using the package `fancyheadings`, in favour of `fancyhdr`. See the example below (I tried to comment the code directly).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% if the global font size is 10pt, the baselineskip of \small
% is 11pt and minimal head height is therefore 33 pt
\usepackage[headheight=33pt]{geometry}

\fancyhf{}{} % clean headers
\fancyhead[L]{\small\begin{tabular}{@{}l} % left header left aligned
  \bfseries Prof.\@ \hbox to 5em{\hrulefill}\\
  Spring 2013\\
  3rd line of left header
  \end{tabular}}
\fancyhead[R]{\small\begin{tabular}{r@{}} % right header right aligned
  \bfseries MEE: \hbox to 5em{\hrulefill}\\
  Homework II\\
  Whatever you want here
  \end{tabular}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% no header line

\pagestyle{fancy}

 % show the page layout, provide dummy text
\usepackage{showframe, lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-30]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in your definition. `_` can not be used outside mathmode as you did. Change it to `\rule` commands.

I used the geometry package to define easier the height and separation of the head.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[headheight=6\baselineskip,headsep=1\baselineskip]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyheadings}

\lhead{\begin{small}Prof. \rule{3cm}{0.1pt}\\Spring 2013\end{small}\\ so \\ keep \\ it}
\chead{\begin{small}\textbf{MEE:}\rule{3cm}{0.1pt}\\Homework II\footnote{This document was made using \LaTeX\ and the amsmath package.}\end{small}\\ if \\ typing \\run}
\rhead{\begin{small}\rule{5cm}{0.1pt}\\Due \rule{3cm}{0.1pt}\end{small}\\ I \\ will\\ over?}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} %removes line under header

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}

\lipsum[1-7]
\end{document}
```